# How to fetch record by weekly in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

I would like to   display records by weeks using entity framework for example if i pass 32 then i need to fetch records which have 32  week of this year.

```
public List<Customer> ByWeek(int year,int week)
 {
  return db.Customers.where(p=>p.Createon.Year==year);
 }
```

I could not find week like year and month please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're probably best off not doing this the way you're doing now: you can instead find the week client-side, and turn the query into `p => p.Createon >= firstDayOfWeek && p.Createon < firstDayOfNextWeek`, which would simplify the query and allow (for example) an index on `Createon` to be used.

Comment: hi @hvd thanks for reply i got it again thanks for great idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with linq to entities, you should use [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx).

```
public List<Customer> ByWeek(int year, int week) {
   return db.Customers.Where(p => 
                   SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", p.Createon) == week && 
                   SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", p.Createon) == year
                   );

}
```

Comment: i got red line on SqlFunctions.

Comment: @user2433270 Sorry : add at top of your class (file) : `using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient`